# BCD Switch Resistor Network for Proportional Voltage Output

Tags: analog

My goal is to wire a BCD switch in a 5 volt system and get a voltage proportional to the 0-9 on the switch.  My first thought was BCD -> R/2R network.  That does not work because the R/2R network expects its inputs to be Vdd or Ground.  The BCD switches produce short-to-common or open-circuit.  Some solutions have occurred to me:

1. Use a digital buffer with pull-ups between the BCD switch and the R/2R network. The 74ALC746 can do this but it seems unlikely that I will find one in stock.
2. Use a BCD switch with both complement and non-complemented outputs.  Those are expensive switches!
3. Use an R/2R/4R/8R network and a constant current source.  Are there R/2R/4R/8R resistor networks?  This seems to be less energy efficient than #1.
4. Use a microcontroller.   That will work but a simple, purely hardware approach is preferred.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use use buffers after the switch as your solution #1 with an R-2R network. A 74HC4050 or 74HC4049 depending on whether the switch is inverting or not.

Or buy resistors that are in the 1:2:4:8 ratio- there are only four parts or so- there's no need for a network. Eg. 10K/20K/40K (two 20K in series)/80.6K. You don't (necessarily) need a constant current source- for example you could use the switch between a negative voltage reference and the input of an inverting amplifier.

Edit:

Eg. [image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how you can decode such a network with only 1:2:4:8 resistors. Could you please add a schematic or some more detailed explanation of what's connected to what?

Comment: @redfast00 see edit above