# Level Adjustment Component

Tags: arduino, level

I am developing simple project of water level alert when water reaches to a certain level (adjusted by user) in inches.

Which electronic component i should use where user can adjust inches?

Like 5, 6, 7 .... 20 inches.

I have searched a lot over internet and found Potentiometer can be used for this purpose. But it is not accurate and depends of input voltage/current etc...

I need smaller component because it will be used in 3x3 inches circuit board with Arduino.

Comment: What do **you** want to use? Potentiometer, potentiometer + display, encoder + display, up/down keys + display. Display can be LCD, OLED, LCD etc.

Answer (score 1):

A coded rotary DIP switch will allow the user to select discrete values (usually 10 or 16 different ones), but will use 4 GPIOs in order to read the selected value.

[image]

Comment: It is very close to my requirement. But i need more than 20 values adjustment.

Comment: Then use multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

You want a BCD thumbwheel switch (sometimes incorrectly called decade counters):

[image]

Picture from [How to read decade counter with minimum pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178469/how-to-read-decade-counter-with-minimum-pins)

You press the buttons to increment or decrement the number, and the number is output at the back in BCD. Unlike a rotary dip switch, they're much easier to fit to panels.